# Вытащить все документы из коллекции кроме одного конкретного

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Такой вопрос: 
Если необходимо вытащить все документы со значениями внутренними кроме идентификатора(`_id`) то:

1. Если обращаться в данном запросе по идентификатору(если это возможно) - добавит ли это скорость извлечения данных?
2. Как реализовать данную задачу которая озвучена выше?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Следующий вариант кода пока что не очень решает данную задачу:

```
const getDatabasesAndCollections = async () => {
  const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
  const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/');

  client.connect();
  const databasesAndCollections = await client.db('startInitialization').collection('databases&Collections');
  console.log(databasesAndCollections.find());
}

getDatabasesAndCollections()


FindCursor {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(topology)]: Topology {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      open: [Function],
      connectionPoolCreated: [Function (anonymous)],    
      connectionPoolClosed: [Function (anonymous)],     
      connectionCreated: [Function (anonymous)],        
      connectionReady: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckOutStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionCheckOutFailed: [Function (anonymous)], 
      connectionCheckedOut: [Function (anonymous)],     
      connectionCheckedIn: [Function (anonymous)],
      connectionPoolCleared: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandSucceeded: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandFailed: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverOpening: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverDescriptionChanged: [Function (anonymous)],
      topologyOpening: [Function (anonymous)],
      topologyClosed: [Function (anonymous)],
      topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      close: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverHeartbeatStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverHeartbeatSucceeded: [Function (anonymous)],
      serverHeartbeatFailed: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 26,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    bson: [Object: null prototype] {
      serialize: [Function: serialize],
      deserialize: [Function: deserialize]
    },
    s: {
      id: 0,
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      seedlist: [Array],
      state: 'connecting',
      description: [TopologyDescription],
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500,
      servers: [Map],
      sessionPool: [ServerSessionPool],
      sessions: Set(0) {},
      credentials: undefined,
      clusterTime: undefined,
      connectionTimers: Set(0) {},
      detectShardedTopology: [Function: detectShardedTopology],
      detectSrvRecords: [Function: detectSrvRecords]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(waitQueue)]: Denque {
      _head: 1,
      _tail: 2,
      _capacity: undefined,
      _capacityMask: 3,
      _list: [Array]
    }
  },
  [Symbol(namespace)]: MongoDBNamespace {
    db: 'startInitialization',
    collection: 'databases&Collections'
  },
  [Symbol(documents)]: [],
  [Symbol(initialized)]: false,
  [Symbol(closed)]: false,
  [Symbol(killed)]: false,
  [Symbol(options)]: {
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    raw: false,
    enableUtf8Validation: true
  },
  [Symbol(filter)]: {},
  [Symbol(builtOptions)]: {
    raw: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    enableUtf8Validation: true,
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Тебе нужны все документы коллекции? Но из всех ключей каждого документа нужно исключить "_id"?
Если так - в запросе к БД можно указать какие ключи исключить при выводе...
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-method-find-projection

Comment: Все документы в которых исключено поле _id `await databasesAndCollections.find({},{_id:0}).forEach(e=>{console.log(e)})`

Comment: перепиши под полноценный формат ответа этот код если хочешь - зачту его как решенный.